# include a php file in all project files or in all php files

Tags: php, include

I have important variables that I want to include in all of my php files in the project and I want that done automatically. How do I do this?

Comment: You are looking for [auto-prepend-file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)

Comment: Justin, very few people are actually looking for auto-prepend-file. That's a configuration option done in the web server and is not very portable at all. I can imagine hosting providers using it to emulate PHP function behavior with some logging or similar, but few PHP develoeprs can use that option for their system design.

Comment: How about autoloading classes with variables defined as properties?

Comment: My immediate reaction is to warn you that it sounds to me as though you're building your website incorrectly.  To pull in a standard list of variables into every file just sounds extremely static and badly thought out.  Why can't you use a concept like class inheritance, or even initiate a class which already includes all your variables?  Otherwise, there really isn't enough information here for us to provide you with useful feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way is to use UrlRewriting.

You redirect each request on `index.php` with get parameters, and this file will load the appropriate content. Then you'll be able to centralize some setting. For example, you just have to put your include in the file `index.php`, and every page will have it.

Answer (score 2):

include this file on every page by using `require()` or `include()`
store all important variable on file (ec. start)
example:

```
<?php require 'start.php'; ?>
```

note:

1. *if you want to ensure that `start.php` **must be read before execute anything else**, then you should use require.*
2. *If you just want to load a ‘not that important’ template header then you can use include function.*